# Refreshing user roles in ASP.NET Identity at a certain point

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, roles, asp.net-mvc-5

I have implemented role-based authentication/authorization on my website using ASP.NET Identity & Owin using the following code:

```
 [HttpPost]
        [ActionName("Login")]
        public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = ctx.Users.Where(x => x.Email == model.Username).FirstOrDefault();
                if (user != null)
                {
                    if (user.PasswordHash == Helpers.PasswordHelper.CreatePasswordHash(model.Password, user.PasswordSalt))
                    {
                        ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
                        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, model.Username));
                        List<Claim> claims = new List<Claim>();
                        var roles = user.UserRoles.Where(x => x.UserId == user.UserId).ToList();
                        foreach (var item in roles)
                        {
                            claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, item.Roles.RoleName));
                        }
                        identity.AddClaims(claims);                     
                        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, model.Username));

                        AuthenticationManager.SignIn(identity);

                        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Index");
                    }
                }
                ModelState.AddModelError("WrongUsernamePassword", "Wrong username or password!");
                return View("Login", model);
            }
            else
            {
                return View("Login",model);
            }
        }
```

My question is, is there  a way for me now to refresh the user roles when they are changed in the DB??

What could I do to achieve this ?

Comment: You can do this => `ctx.Entry(user).Reload();` or `await ctx.Entry(user).ReloadAsync();`

Comment: That doesnt works :(

Comment: @CodeNotFound I think I haven't been very clear with my question.. I need to refresh the Claims that were initially set in Identity upon login... I update the DB at a certain point, and then I need to reload the Claims within the identity...